# Excel VBA: Copy data from range of cells with a variable as the column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of cells from one sheet to another. It searches for an empty column, then copies the current data. However, it will not compile and fails at

```
Sheets("Archive").Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(100, x)).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("H2:H100").Value
```

The full code is:

```
Sub Generate()
Dim i As Boolean
Dim x As Long
i = False
x = 2
Do While i = False
    If Sheets("Archive").Cells(2, x) = "" Then
    i = True
Sheets("Archive").Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(100, x)).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("H2:H100").Value    
MsgBox "Done!"
End If
    x = x + 1
    'debug
    MsgBox "Iteration " & x
Loop     
Sheets("Main").Range("H2:H100").Value = Sheets("Password Generator").Range("A2:A100").Value
Sheets("Main").Range("I2:I100").Value = Sheets("Password Generator").Range("B2:B100").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: **EVERY** Range object needs to be assigned to a parent sheet `Sheets("Archive").Range(Sheets("Archive").Cells(2, x), Sheets("Archive").Cells(100, x)).Value...`

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched SO for a solid hour before making an account. Sorry about the duplicate.